# Restart HTML5 audio element before it completes (JS: setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, html, audio

This JS code refers to an HTML5 Audio element that plays a 4-second .mp3:

```
function playTone(){
    document.getElementById('tone').play();
};
setTimeout(playTone,2000);
setTimeout(playTone,7000);
```

This works to play the tone twice. However, if I set the second setTimeout to 3000 (which I would like to do) it only plays once, because the first mp3 has not finished playing. Is there a way get around this? How can I get the Audio element to restart from the beginning before it has completed?

For my purposes, I would like to call the same element, rather than dynamically creating a new one. The context is that I would like a selection of these audio elements on the page, and use JS to play them as a musical instrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the current time of the audio to the beginning before you play the audio. This function should work.

```
function playTone(){
    var tone = document.getElementById('tone');
    tone.currentTime = 0;
    tone.play();
}
```

Comment: Yes! Easy! Thank you!